# Flip Animation Using Core Animation Showing Reversed Contents

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

Here is the result that I get:

[image]

If I set the `doubleSided` property of layer 4 as No, the whole layer disappears. I know that already. But then, how can I show yet with correct content orientation?

Comment: Do the animation in two parts. At the halfway point, between the two parts, flip the layer the other way around and move the anchor point to the other side.

Comment: I did that right after writing the Q and it worked like a charm :) Can you write your comment as an answer with little bit of details, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the animation in two parts. At the halfway point, when the layer is side-on to the camera so you can’t see it, flip the layer the other way around and move the anchor point to the other side, and swap out the contents of the layer if you need to.

Unfortunately, I don’t have any sample code, because the last time I did this was on iOS 4, and the <strike>pile of hacks</strike> view-based animations that I was using don’t appear to work on layers any more. You could post your own code and accept your own answer if you want.